# ImportError: No module named 'torchvision.datasets.mnist'

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, importerror, torchvision

Even after installing pytorch, this error is coming for this line.

```
from torchvision import datasets
```

Comment: Just to confirm, did you install `torchvision` as well? `pip3 install torchvision`

Comment: Try reinstalling torchvision with `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall torchvision`

Answer (score 6):

If you're using anaconda distribution, first install torchvision using:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge torchvision
```

If the package is not installed, then it will be installed. Else, it will throw the message

> # All requested packages already installed.

After this, try to import the `torchvision.datasets` as you mentioned.

```
In [1]: from torchvision import datasets 

In [2]: dir(datasets)  
Out[2]: 
['CIFAR10',
 'CIFAR100',
 'CocoCaptions',
 'CocoDetection',
 'DatasetFolder',
 'EMNIST',
 'FakeData',
 'FashionMNIST',
 'ImageFolder',
 'LSUN',
 'LSUNClass',
 'MNIST',
 'Omniglot',
 'PhotoTour',
 'SEMEION',
 'STL10',
 'SVHN',
 ....,
 ....
]
```

As you can see from above listing of `dir(datasets)`, the dataset class for `MNIST` is listed which will be the case when the torchvision package is installed correctly.

Comment: For any other distribution (not Anaconda), the [PyTorch homepage](https://pytorch.org/) provides a convenient tool that lets you input your environment, and return a command to install the relevant package, if you just scroll down a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

mnist must be capitalized

torchvision.datasets.MNIST

Comment: please vote to close typo questions instead of answering them. you can comment explaining the typo. answering questions that should be closed is discouraged (see [answer])